Running Python script in C#
>System.Exception: 'Python script exited with code 1.
Output: 
Errors: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\users_j77wa4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openseespy\opensees\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from openseespywin.opensees import *
  File "C:\Users\users_j77wa4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openseespywin\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Python version 3.8 is needed for Windows

>During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\users_j77wa4\Desktop\ProjectXOutput\3d_model.py", line 2, in <module>
    import openseespy.opensees as ops
  File "C:\Users\users_j77wa4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openseespy\opensees\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Failed to import openseespy on Windows.')
RuntimeError: Failed to import openseespy on Windows.

I got the above RunTime error when I execute the below code:
public static void Execute3DRendererModelScript()
{
    SaveScript3DRendererModel();

    string scriptPath = Properties.Settings.Default.OutputFolder + "\\3d_model.py";
    string pythonPath = Properties.Settings.Default.PythonInterpreter;

    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = pythonPath,
            Arguments = scriptPath,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        }
    };

    process.Start();

    // Read the output/error of the Python script
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    // Wait for the process to finish
    process.WaitForExit();

    // Handle errors if any
    if (process.ExitCode != 0)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Python script exited with code {process.ExitCode}.\nOutput: {output}\nErrors: {errors}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Python script executed successfully.");
        Console.WriteLine("Output: " + output);
    }

}

However when I open python3.11.exe then paste the my script here it works fine.
What is the problem here?
I am trying to create .html file for openseespy 3D Renderer Model

Your code seems to not have issues, however, the Python version is not supported by the library that you are trying to use.
It seems that the latest version which is supported is Python 3.10, but you have Python 3.11. (https://github.com/zhuminjie/OpenSeesPy/issues/61#issuecomment-1672058969)

I tried to see run the script in Pyton3.11.exe then i watching the responses of the code in exe it also gives errors but it continue to execute code and create a file. Interestingly in PhyCharm when run the script i did not take any errors. In C# when the error occurs it is directly stop the execution.

PhyCharm might use a different phyton version! IntelliJ includes with their IDEs most of the time some programs as extras to make sure certain functionalities work. You get errors because you running with the wrong version installed, install 3.10 as mentioned by the module creator.
